# xhttp.send works once but fails the 2nd time

Tags: javascript, assembly

I have the following javascript that works happily the 1st time but fails the second time..

```
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();               
    xhttp.open("POST","FINDMOVES",false);
    xhttp.send(text);
```

This send is actually being received by the server and a respone is written by the server. The server is my own and written in assembler.
The java console reports:-

POST http://localhost:1024/FINDMOVES net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:1024/FINDMOVES'.

This code works happily where it is used in other programs.

I am aware that:- "[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience" but it is not java's decision as to what my end user experience is like. It is mine.

Anyone got any clues ??

further to this...(and some background)
I have a runtime module that acts as a web server. This is used to serve on-line programs and therefore be portable between windows/linux. It is statically linked to application programs.
I have a dozen application programs happily using this server.
I have 1 near identical application that is okay but it's "twin" progran is failing. I have been stepping through the programs for a couple of days now and I have noticed the following:-

The SYS_ACCEPT call returns the same file descriptor for all programs that work while in the failing program, after a few calls, it returns a different file descriptor and as soon as that is the case the web browser does not see the response (even though it was written without error)

Anyone know what's going on here ?

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone but you to debug this.  It's *far* from a [mcve].  Presumably your server is buggy and fails to answer the 2nd request, or fails to answer it correctly.  Use your browser to trace the HTTP request and see what actual response was received, if any.  (Or wireshark or other packet-logging on the loopback interface.)

Comment: If your server is running under Linux, you could trace the system calls it makes by running it under `strace`, or attaching an strace to it after it starts.  Once you find out what system calls it didn't make, or made with wrong args, then use a debugger to single-step your program while handling that request.  Since you didn't post any network or system call debug traces, or source for your program, nobody else can do this for you.

Comment: Also, Javascript is not Java.  They just picked a confusingly similar name for a very different language that had some overlap in use-cases, back in the day when Sun hoped that Java applets running in browsers would be a thing.

Comment: Peter...I think I covered these things in my question, but if it was not clear let me elaborate..  I have discounted the server being buggy for a couple of reason. 1) It runs happily for many other applications and 2 I am stepping thru it using gdb and I can see what is coming in and going out. I see the javascript hit the "xhttp.send(text)" and produce the error BUT at the same time I see the server receive the text and write a response. It does it for many apllications and it does it the 1st thru for this particular application. Of course that doesn't mean it isnt buggy

Comment: Are you sure it actually sent the response successfully?  Use `strace` to make sure the right system call happened.  And if that's the case, then try wireshark or something to make sure that response is making it to the browser.  (Or see where it gets lost.)

Comment: I tried strace Peter but it showed nothing unusual, however it did lead me to discover a problem with my server. You know those bugs where you ask yourself, "well why did it ever work". I believe there is more to it though as the browser seems to be sending a different dataset to previously. It's getting late, trying again tomorrow

Comment: @Peter Cordes - I have been running this with wireshark and this is what I see sent in gdb - "HTTP /1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n51" This is what I see using wireshark - "HTTP /1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n51" and this is what I display in FireFox - "5,1 HTTP /1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n51" - This is a problem before I even get to my original problem !!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is not what I would have expected and I came across it completely by accident when I commented out some file access in the application program to make the strace ouput clearer.

The application was at fault in that it opened a file in an initialisation section but mistakenly closed it each time it sent a response back to the server. It effect it opened once but closed many times. In some way this confused the linux kernel (?) and it was made evident in the SYS_ACCEPT call.

I have to admit, I do not understand why this occurs so if someone can shed some light on why this happens I would appreciate it. For now though it looks like everything is back to working again.

Oh, I was getting a -512 back from the SYS_ACCEPT call but could never find out what that represented. Perhaps it means "Hey dude, stop closing that bloody file" !!

Comment: system call return values from -4095 .. -1 are `-errno` codes.  `-512` is outside the range Linux actually uses (see `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno*.h`) so it's unlikely to be the real value.  I'd expect `-EBADF` if you accidentally closed the socket with a rogue `close` or otherwise corrupted wherever you were keeping the `fd`, or `-EMFILE` if you were leaking fds and eventually hit the per-process limit; the man page (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html#ERRORS) lists the possible errors.  `strace` would have decoded its actual return value for you.